# reverse a string recursively

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

```
string rev(string s,int n,int st)
{
if(st==n||st>n)
{
    return s;    
}
swap(s[st],s[n]);
rev(s,n-1,st+1);
return s;

}
```

st is 0 n is lenght-1 and s is string. I am trying to print the reverse of the string but I am not getting the answer.
like the sentence is "Geeks" the the output is "seekG"
actually my string is getting reverse but it is again getting back to normal after hitting the base case. How can I terminate my recursion once I have reached the base case.

Comment: _"How can I terminate my recursion once I have reached the base case."_...  Recursion routines need to include an [exit criteria](http://mark.random-article.com/weber/ada/week13.html) within the function

Comment: Using recursion to solve this problem looks articifial a little bit. An homework constraint?

Comment: @Damien nope i am trying to understand recursion so I am practicing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not return the original string from the argument with two swapped chars. Return the final result. Replace

```
rev(s,n-1,st+1);
return s;
```

with

```
return rev(s,n-1,st+1);
```

`if(st==n||st>n)` better is `if(st >= n)`

Comment: It's probably better to return the original `s` or nothing at all, otherwise a pointer to the middle of the string will be returned to the original caller, which probably isn't very useful!

Comment: Which of s, n or st is a pointer?

Comment: Sorry, question was also tagged "C" originally, so I was thinking `string` was `char *` from cs50.h or something! Also, my comment didn't make sense anyway because it wasn't returning a pointer to the middle of the string!